# Tornare sui propri passi

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-request

Cosa significa "tornare sui propri passi"? Significa per caso tornare indietro su un tracciato di scelte organizzate a labirinto?

Comment: Nessun bisogno di pensare a labirinti o a percorsi tortuosi... immagina di ripercorrere a ritroso le orme che hai lasciato sulla sabbia di una spiaggia. Nel senso metaforico significa *rivedere le proprie scelte*, cambiare il modo di pensare o di affrontare un problema o, anche, la vita.

Comment: @N74: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: @Charo Fatto come richiesto, ma penso che le mie risposte tendano ad essere un po' povere di contenuto. Magari qualcun'altro poteva meglio elaborare il mio commento in una risposta più approfondita.

Comment: @N74, a volte non c'è molto da elaborare ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dopo aver fatto una serie di scelte ed essersi accorti che non portavano da nessuna parte, "tornare sui propri passi" indica metaforicamente il tentativo di cambiamento a posteriori di queste scelte ritornando indietro nella fase di scelta iniziale.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Nessun bisogno di pensare a labirinti o a percorsi tortuosi... immagina di ripercorrere a ritroso le orme che hai lasciato sulla sabbia di una spiaggia.

Nel senso metaforico significa *rivedere le proprie scelte*, cambiare il modo di pensare o di affrontare un problema o, anche, la vita.

Comment: Quindi non cambiare la propria posizione su una promessa,ma rendersi conto delle scelte già fatte e decidere come meglio scegliere nel futuro se capisco bene. Correggimi se ho capito male. Grazie.

Comment: In particolare, volevo sapere quale differenza c'è tra questa espressione e l'espressione "mangiarsi le proprie parole".

Comment: ***Ri**mangiarsi le proprie parole* è l'equivalente dell'inglese *eating one's words* (o *eating crow*). Significa ammettere di aver detto/scritto/espresso parole sbagliate. *Tornare sui propri passi* ha un significato più ampio perché include qualunque tipo di scelta, non solo le opinioni espresse.

Comment: Ti dirò, ci starebbe quasi di esprimere questo tuo ulteriore dubbio in un'altra domanda. Anche perché, sebbene sia d'accordo con @lserni sul secondo paragrafo, *rimangiarsi le proprie parole* significa *venire meno ad una promessa data* piuttosto che ammettere di aver cambiato idea.

Comment: Hai ragione, @N74 . *eating one's words* è più frequentemente reso con **doversi** rimangiare le proprie parole (o con il *fare* rimangiare: "Gli ho fatto rimangiare le sue parole/bugie/offese"). Quando uno se le rimangia senza costrizione :-), in genere il senso è che sta venendo meno alla propria parola.